# Argument of a complex number with assumptions

Tags: simplifying-expressions, complex, assumptions

I am trying to calculate the argument of a complex number:

```
Arg[Cos[y]*Exp[I x]]
```

where both x and y are real. The solution is clearly x, but I can't get it with Mathematica! I tried adding an assumption

```
Simplify[Arg[Cos[y]*Exp[I x]], y > 0]

Assuming[{x \[Element] Reals, y \[Element] Reals}, Arg[Cos[y]*Exp[I x]]]
```

but it doesn't work. Anyone has an idea? How can I get Mathematica to output x?

Comment: The solution isn't $x$, it's $(x \text{ mod } 2\pi) - \pi$ under Mathematica's conventions.  Perhaps adding the assumption `- \Pi < x < \Pi` will help?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I tried `Simplify[Arg[Cos[y]*Exp[I x]], {y > 0, -Pi < x < Pi}]`, but I still don't get the answer x mod 2Pi

Comment: `Cos[y]` can be negative.

Comment: That's a good point: I run `Assuming[{0 < x < 0.1, 0 < y < 0.1}, Refine[Arg[Cos[y]*Exp[I x]]]]` and now I get `Arg[E^(I x)]` as a solution. How do I get x as an output now?

Answer (score 4):

Plot it to see it

```
Plot3D[{x, Arg[Cos[y]*Exp[I x]]}, {x, -7, 7}, {y, -5, 5}, 
 PlotPoints -> 100, PlotStyle -> {Red, Blue}]

FullSimplify[Arg[Cos[y]*Exp[I x]], {-Pi/2 < y < Pi/2, -Pi < x < Pi}]

(*   x   *)
```

Answer (score 4):

As pointed out by @Akku14,

```
FullSimplify[
     Arg[Cos[y]*Exp[I*x]],
     Assumptions->{-Pi<x<Pi,-Pi/2<y<Pi/2}]
```

does give `x` as requested. The assumptions on `y` are such that `Cos[y]` is positive. But if you change the assumptions a bit, it may not always produce exactly what you want. For example, if you say modify the second inequality to `Pi/2<y<3*Pi/2` where `Cos[y]` is negative, it will not evaluate `Arg`. So you are right that `Arg` is a function that can be tricky to deal with in a symbolic calculation.

The [`Arg`-documentation](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Arg.html) acknowledges this with "`Arg[z]` is left unevaluated if `z` is not a numeric quantity". Almost all examples in the documentation are for numeric input.

There are various ways to deal with this in practice. You could use an explicit replacement such as

```
yourExpression /. {Arg[Exp[I*x]]->x}
```

to achieve this particular transformation. Mathematica cannot do this automatically because it is only true with certain assumptions about `x`, but an explicit replacement is one way to bring the extra information that you have about your `x` into the symbolic calculation and move on. See [here for more info on transformations](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/TransformationRulesAndDefinitions.html).